# Netsuite Advanced PDF/HTML code ifelse statement

Tags: html, pdf, if-statement, freemarker, netsuite

I need some assistance in the correct way to format this code for a item fulfillment in Netsuite;

```
  <td><#if item.units != null>Units<#else>${tranline.units}</#if></td>
```

I want the PDF form to show the Units of Measure (i.e. units) and if there is no particular UOM specificied for the item, to say **UNITS** instead of displaying nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example looks correct to me, aside from the values being in the wrong places.  In my PDF templates, I do not use NULL, either.  Below is how I have a similar item written.

```
<#if item.units=="">
  Units
<#else>
  ${tranline.units}
</#if>
```